# MTLBuffer corrupted data

Tags: c++, metal

I've started to play with metal api and include it in my renderer as new api. However I'm having issues with data in my `MTLBuffer` after creation and initialization.

I have some api agnostic class for vertex buffers and streams, which I use like this:

```
// Fill vertex streams with data
    auto& positionStream = vb.GetDataStream<0>().AddData(
         // Quad 1
         Vec4{ -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{  x.xf, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{ -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },

         // Quad 2
         Vec4{ -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f },
         Vec4{ -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f }
    );
```

Where Vec4 is really simpler struct:

```
struct Vec4
{
    float x{ 0.0f };
    float y{ 0.0f };
    float z{ 0.0f };
    float w{ 0.0f };
};
```

Each data stream of vertex buffer is backed by MTLBuffer. However when I create and initialize this stream with data, `x` element which I marked in code sample as `x.x` contains some garbage value. If I set this value to anything it's always garbage. I use some other streams for indexes, colors, texcoords and all of those data is correct. I create buffers with call to

```
[device newBufferWithBytes:data length:length options:0]
```

This is what I see when I capture frame:

[image]
Edit: I've also noticed that this happens on my first MTLBuffer creation, I've tried to create MTLBuffer for color data first and then for positions and colors got corrupted and positions are fine.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: What's `length` in your `newBufferWithBytes:...` call? Does it help to do `[buffer didModifyRange:NSMakeRange(0, length)]` after creating it? (Shouldn't be necessary, but you never know.)

Comment: @KenThomases it's 128 for both streams (MTLBuffers, positions & colors) which is correct. Both buffers have 4096B allocated size. Btw currently I didn't really care about performance of buffer creation, a.k.a I do not create staging buffers to upload data, so my buffers are shared (I have Intel GPU anyway, so it doesn't matter) and therefore I can't call ```didModifyRange``` as that is valid only for private buffers

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to find a problem. I'm on MacOS 10.15 Catalina Beta (19A501i), with XCode-Beta. I've tried to build app in non-beta version of XCode and everything seems to be correct even after inspecting those buffers in gpu debugger.

I was using Xcode-beta (Version 11.0 beta (11M336w)) before which seems to be the issue.